# Intermittent refresh issues when scrolling up and down on 9810 + Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am facing a strange issue with screen scrolling on 9810 device and simulator. 
I have a complete order screen, which is shown when the order of the user is confirmed.

At the top there is Vertical Field Manager which contains another VerticalFieldManager ( containing Label Fields and buttonFields ) and a FlowFieldManager (containing images).
Now the problem that i am facing is that whenever i scroll the screen up and down , there are many gray lines appearing on the screen. It seems as if there is some screen refresh issue with the device. I tested on previous OS (4.5, 4.5 4.7 5.0) version, everything is working just fine on them. The problem is arising on OS version above 6.0 .

[image: Distorted Image]

While the correct screen must be like

[image: Correct Image]

As you can see these gray lines appear whenevr i scroll screen up and down. Any ideas how to rectify this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am very sorry for the late reply. However i fixed the issue by myself. I just overrided the paintBackground method in my class and inside that i wrote graphics.clear(). This seems to fix this scrolling issue. I will try Michael method too though.

Answer (score 4):

In the first image, it looks like you are trying to add a shadow effect at the top of the screen. The vertical field manager uses some graphics optimization to improve scroll performance.  Instead of repainting everything, it picks up the pixels on screen in the layout area, and shifts them.  This works so long as all the painting code is relative to the virtual extent.

Certain UI effect, like a shadow effect, are relative to the screen, rather than the virtual extent, so this optimization picks up those effects and copies them elsewhere, which looks bad. It also tends to look just like your first image.

There are two ways to fix this:

1. Turn off the optimization.  Override [isScrollCopyable](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#isScrollCopyable%28%29) to return false.  Your visual problems should go away, but scrolling performance will suffer.
2. Don't add UI effects on top of a scrollable area.

Comment: Great answer. I've encountered a similar issue and your answer saved me a lot of time. My problem was that I was drawing a tooltip on a `VerticalFieldManager`'s paintable region that was copied on vertical scrolling. Thanks!